# Частичное обновление информации о пользователи

Tags: sql, node.js

Понадобилось частичное обновление информацции о пользователи.

Например, если `user_name` не приходит в запросе, то оставить его не тронутым в базе данных, то есть не изменяя.

Мой контролер `users`:

```
let user = new User(
    req.body.user_name,
    req.body.user_email,
    req.body.user_password,
    req.body.about,
    req.body.user_avatar,
    req.body.notifications,
    req.body.locations
);
bcrypt.hash(user.user_password, config.salt.saltRounds, (err, hash) => {
    db.query(user.updateUserByIdSQL(decoded.user_id, hash), (err) => {
        if (!err) {
            return res.status(200).json({
                            message: `User updated with id = ${decoded.user_id}.`,
                    });
        }
        return res.status(401).json({
            err: err
        });
    });
});
```

Моя модель `user`:

```
updateUserByIdSQL(user_id, hash) {
    let sql = `UPDATE USERS SET USER_NAME='${this.user_name}', USER_EMAIL='${this.user_email}', USER_PASSWORD='${hash}', USER_AVATAR='${this.user_avatar}',
        ABOUT='${this.about}', NOTIFICATIONS='${this.notifications}', LOCATIONS='${this.locations}' WHERE USER_ID='${user_id}'`;
    return sql;
}
```

Сейчас у меня обновляются полностью все поля. И если я не отпровляю одно из полей, то приходит `undefined`. Как можно частично обновить информацию о пользователе?

Comment: динамически строить содержимое set в зависимости от наличия полей

Comment: к сожалению, я не очень понимаю как это сделать

Comment: Почитайте на досуге https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp